# regular expression incorrectly matching % and $

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regular expression in JavaScript to allow numeric and `(,.+() -)` character in phone field

my regex is `[0-9-,.+() ]`

It works for numeric as well as above six characters but it also allows characters like `%` and `$` which are not in above list.

Comment: How are you using it exactly?

Comment: This is because you have an unescaped hyphen. `0-9-,` is telling it `all characters from 0 to 9 to ,`, as well as your `.` saying `all characters except newline`

Comment: `.` matches everything, escape it

Comment: [regex for telephone numbers is a solved problem.](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=telephone+regex)

Comment: but i need six characters like hypen,plus sign,space,comma,dot,brace and numeric.how to write it?

Comment: [`"1230-,.$".match(/[0-9-,.+() ]/g)`](http://jsconsole.com/?%221230-%2C.%24%22.match%28%2F[0-9-%2C.%2B%28%29%20]%2Fg%29) does not match `$`, at least in Firefox.

Comment: @PaulS - That has a mistake and a half: `.` should not be escaped in a character class, and `-` usually works well *after another range*: `0-9` `-`

Comment: @Kobi *Should* not? I do it because it doesn't hurt and it helps readability (IMHO). But you're right; it is not necessary to escape `.`, or even `+`. `-` will need to be escaped if not escaping it will make an invalid range, such as in `[9-,]` but not in `[0-9-,]` because `0-9` is already a range.

Answer (score 4):

Even though you don't have to, I always make it a point to escape metacharacters (easier to read and less pain):

```
[0-9\-,\.+\(\) ]
```

But this won't work like you expect it to because it will only match *one* valid character while allowing other invalid ones in the string. I imagine you want to match the entire string with *at least one* valid character:

```
^[0-9\-,\.\+\(\) ]+$
```

Your original regex is not actually matching `%`. What it is doing is matching valid characters, but the problem is that it only matches **one** of them. So if you had the string `435%`, it matches the `4`, and so the regex reports that it has a match.

If you try to match it against just *one* invalid character, it won't match. So your original regex doesn't match the string `%`:

```
> /[0-9\-,\.\+\(\) ]/.test("%")
  false

> /[0-9\-,\.\+\(\) ]/.test("44%5")
  true

> "444%6".match(/[0-9\-,\.+\(\) ]/)
  ["4"] //notice that the 4 was matched.
```

Going back to the point about escaping, I find that it is easier to escape it rather than worrying about the different rules where specific metacharacters are valid in a character class. For example, `-` is only valid in the following cases:

- When used in an actual character class with proper-order such as `[a-z]` (but *not* `[z-a]`)
- When used as the first or last character, or by itself, so `[-a]`, `[a-]`, or `[-]`.
- When used *after* a range like `[0-9-,]` or `[a-d-j]` (but keep in mind that `[9-,]` is invalid and `[a-d-j]` does not match the letters `e` through `f`).

For these reasons, I escape metacharacters to make it clear that I want to match the actual character itself and to remove ambiguities.

Comment: @KingKongFrog The OP's regex itself is wrong because it is not trying to match the entire string. Please look at my update.

Comment: My understanding of the question isn't to match an entire phone number but to check whether a character is allowed and if so return true.

Comment: @DrCord You will still need to match the entire string to make sure that it contains no invalid characters. You *could* check the negative case, i.e., to see if it matches `[^0-9\-,\.+\(\) ]` i.e., anything that is *not* in that class, in which case the number is invalid. But testing for the positive case is easier to follow.

Comment: That depends, with alot of new validation you just want to check each user character entry and if is on the allow list then let it be typed.

Comment: @DrCord That depends on the user interaction paradigm that is being followed, which really isn't in the scope of this question (and OP didn't specify). :)

Answer (score 2):

You just need to anchor your regex:

```
^[0-9-,.+() ]+$
```

In character class special char doesn't need to be escaped, except  `]` and `-`.

But, these char are not escaped when:

`]` is alone in the char class `[]]`
`-` is at the begining `[-abc]` or at the end `[abc-]`  of the char class or after the last end range `[a-c-x]`

Answer (score -1):

Escape characters with special meaning in your RegExp. If you're not sure and it isn't an alphabet character, it usually doesn't hurt to escape it, too.

If the whole string must match, include the start `^` and end `$` of the string in your RegExp, too.

```
/^[\d\-,\.\+\(\) ]*$/
```

Comment: 2323dfdf%%^^&^&^#$34#$@#@# shouldn't be a match

Comment: No...3434433434 is not a match now

Comment: Nope...blank is a match now. ;)

Comment: @PaulS. Blank string matches :) Use `+` instead of `*`.

Comment: OP didn't specify behaviour for empty string.

Comment: @PaulS. OP said it was a phone field, so I assumed that a blank phone number is invalid.

Comment: thanks for all for your answers.but when i refresh page + sign disappear ?why this is happing